# gstreamer pipeline program using OpenCV 2.4.8 throws run-time error

Tags: opencv, dll, gstreamer, avcodec

On Windows x64, I have a gstream pipeline program using OpenCV 2.4.8 throws run-time error about the procedure  entry point findHomography not located in library avcodec-55.dll.

Here is the exact message on the dialog box:

"The procedure entry point ?findHomography@cv@@YA?AVMat@AEBV_InputArray@1@0HNAEBV_OutputArray@1@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library avcode-55.dll."

I have no clue how to debug this issue or what to try. I appreciate your pointers if you come across similar issue or suggest me how to debug such issue.

Regards,
Amit!

Comment: This looks like it is not able to link the library. Have you checked your linker/include settings for openCV are correct?

Comment: This run-time error goes away if I use debug OpenCV dlls. Still no idea why release OpenCV dlls give run-time  error. Hoping someone will know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> This run-time error goes away if I use debug OpenCV dlls. Still no
>   idea why release OpenCV dlls give run-time error. Hoping someone will
>   know about it. Thanks!

From this comment the answer to your question is definitely one of the following options.

1. You have not downloaded or built the OpenCV Libraries in release mode (the would be named something like opencv_Core248.dll) & you will need to do so and link them in.
2. You have linked inside visual studio the opencv_core249 **d**.dll libraries and not linked in the release libraries which do not have the d